# Is it legal to list parties not willing to take part in a survey?

Tags: data-protection, data-ownership

I am building a website where hospitals, schools and hotels would be rated by referring to several factors. I need to collect the data (certificates, documents, etc...) from the hospitals/schools/hotels to be able to compile a report on them. In case some of them refuse to cooperate, I am willing to list them as "unrated". Is this legal?

**Note**: Participation in the survey is free of charge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing illegal (in the U.S. at least) about truthfully disclosing that someone did not answer a survey and this is rather common to do in political surveys and not that usual in ratings of educational institutions.

Of course, if you untruthfully state that an organization did not answer the survey when they actually did, that could be problematic, and this doesn't necessarily mean that it is good business policy that take that approach.